# Memory layout problem when debugging, flashing works fine

Tags: openocd

My openocd configuration script:

```
# Configuration mode
telnet_port 4444
gdb_port 3333
source [find interface/ftdi/olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h.cfg]
adapter_khz 0
source [find target/at91sam7x512.cfg]

# Command mode
init
reset init
```

What my gdb session after starting openocd in another terminal looks like:

```
Reading symbols from /home/sw3/arm_workspace/Linuxization/main.out...done.
(gdb) target remote localhost:3333
Remote debugging using localhost:3333
warning: Overlapping regions in memory map: ignoring
0x00000050 in ?? ()
```

With different openocd configuration options and different openocd version, the same source, includeing the linker script, work fine.

**What does this warning mean and where should I be looking to correct it?**

Just some more info, to show the physical memory layout. Strangely, telnet communication reports banks as 0 and 1, while gdb monitor command reports **two 0 banks**:

```
(gdb) monitor flash banks
#0 : sam7x512.flash.0 (at91sam7) at 0x00100000, size 0x00040000, buswidth 4, chipwidth 0
#0 : sam7x512.flash.1 (at91sam7) at 0x00100000, size 0x00040000, buswidth 4, chipwidth 0
```

Later the debugger breaks normally at main(), but stepping produces:

```
(gdb) step
Single stepping until exit from function _user_app_start,
which has no line number information.
stepi ignored. GDB will now fetch the register state from the target.

Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00110000 in _user_app_start ()
```

Those symptoms hint something to anyone?

Comment: Which OpenOCD version do you use?

Comment: It looks like you may have a lot of things going on... linker script that may not match the debugger interface's understanding of the device, some system support libraries perhaps built without debug info...

Comment: @TurboJ, `Open On-Chip Debugger 0.7.0 (2013-08-16-13:27)`

Comment: [workaround](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/80141/what-do-these-openocd-cpu-states-mean/80332#80332)