# What do these OpenOCD CPU states mean?

Tags: arm, jtag, openocd

Here is what the documentation has to say:

```
— Command: reset
— Command: reset run
— Command: reset halt
— Command: reset init

    Perform as hard a reset as possible, using SRST if possible. All defined
    targets will be reset, and target events will fire during the reset sequence.

    The optional parameter specifies what should happen after the reset. If there is 
    no parameter, a reset run is executed. The other options will not work on all 
    systems. See Reset Configuration.

        run Let the target run
        halt Immediately halt the target
        init Immediately halt the target, and execute the reset-init script
```

From [OpenOCD Commands](http://openocd.sourceforge.net/doc/html/General-Commands.html)

I open OpenOCD, then in another terminal I run arm-none-eabi-gdb end execute `monitor reset halt` in order to tell the target to reset and halt the processor, in order to later setup braekpoints and run.

However, the responce from the processor is often different:

```
(gdb) monitor reset halt
JTAG tap: sam7x512.cpu tap/device found: 0x3f0f0f0f (mfg: 0x787, part: 0xf0f0, ver: 0x3)
srst pulls trst - can not reset into halted mode. Issuing halt after reset.
target state: halted
target halted in ARM state due to debug-request, current mode: FIQ
cpsr: 0x600000d1 pc: 0x00000050
NOTE! DCC downloads have not been enabled, defaulting to slow memory writes. Type 'help dcc'.
NOTE! Severe performance degradation without fast memory access enabled. Type 'help fast'.
```

Other times, it goes this way:

```
target state: halted
target halted in ARM state due to debug-request, current mode: Abort
cpsr: 0x600000d7 pc: 0x00000044
```

Yet another times (within the same run, I just opened gdb and run monitor reset halt a bunch of times):

```
target state: halted
target halted in ARM state due to debug-request, current mode: Undefined instruction
cpsr: 0x600000db pc: 0x00000038
```

What are those states?

Comment: Is the processor running a valid program with all its trap handlers configured?

Comment: No event handlers have been declared.

Answer (score 3):

I worked around my problem. Still very interested to learn about those states, though!

I botched the connection through port 3333, and used openocd's piping capabilities:

.gdbinit

```
# Open openocd and pipe data throudh stdin/stdout.
# Openocd quits after gdb exits.
target remote | /usr/local/bin/openocd -f linux_config.cfg
```

openocd.cfg:

```
gdb_port pipe
```

And it magically worked.